# Не растягиваются компоненты на форме Java (Swing).

Tags: jpanel, jframe, java, swing

Давно не использовал Swing, уже и подзабыл что, да как. Создаю объект JPanel, задаю ей менеджер компоновки GridBagLayout. Располагаю элементы. Потом ложу эту панель на свою JFrame. Необходимо, что бы таблица растягивалась, а кнопки нет. Но у меня походу вся панель, содержащая компоненты, не растягивается, поэтому как бы внутри тоже ничего не меняется. Ткните пожалуйста, где я туплю.

```
    package forms;

import info.Informer;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

/**
 * User: Jakeroid
 * Date: 24-11-2012
 * Time: 17:38
 */
public class MainForm extends JFrame {
    public MainForm() {
        super(Informer.getInfoString());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(500, 250);

        JPanel content = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

        ImageIcon addIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resource/add.png"));
        ImageIcon editIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resource/edit.png"));
        ImageIcon deleteIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resource/delete.png"));
        ImageIcon updateIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resource/update.png"));

        JButton addButton = new JButton(addIcon);
        JButton editButton = new JButton(editIcon);
        JButton deleteButton = new JButton(deleteIcon);
        JButton updateButton = new JButton(updateIcon);

        //Массив содержащий заголоки таблицы
        Object[] headers = { "Name", "Surname", "Telephone" };

        //Массив содержащий информацию для таблицы
        Object[][] data = {
                { "John", "Smith", "1112221" },
                { "Ivan", "Black", "2221111" },
                { "George", "White", "3334444" },
                { "Bolvan", "Black", "2235111" },
                { "Serg", "Black", "2221511" },
                { "Pussy", "Black", "2221111" },
                { "Tonya", "Red", "2121111" },
                { "Elise", "Green", "2321111" },
        };

        JTable accountsTable = new JTable(data, headers);

        //setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        content.add(updateButton, c);

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        content.add(addButton, c);

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 2;
        content.add(editButton, c);

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 3;
        content.add(deleteButton, c);

        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridheight = 4;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(accountsTable);
        content.add(scrollPane, c);

        getContentPane().add(content, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
c.weightx = 1.0;
c.weighty = 1.0;
c.gridx = 1;
c.gridy = 0;
c.gridheight = 4;
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(accountsTable);
content.add(scrollPane, c);
```